# ASPxGridView PopupEditForm Doesn't Reload

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

I'm using a modal `PopupEditForm` to edit rows in my `ASPxGridView`.
There is an image and upload control inside this form. The old image is being loaded to this `ASPxImage` for preview and user can upload a new image. But when user does it, even though I change the url of image to new uploaded image url, new image doesn't appear. But if I update the row, it updates the url and shows the new image next time I click to update row.
So there's a problem like `PopupEditForm` is not being called again. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should learn very good [`PopupEditForm`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9093).

Read and learn this example [Grid Editing - Popup Edit Form](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/PopupEditForm.aspx) .

Then If you can't solve your problem, and you have `Devexpress` licence, you should ask it in [Devexpress Support](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/)

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/SearchResults.aspx#cD1UNHxQNXwwc2VhcmNodGV4dD1Qb3B1cCBFZGl0IEZvcm0=

Comment: I believe I've made enough research then asked a question here. I'd expect an answer not a recommendation but that's something, thank you. StackOverFlow seemed faster than DX Support to me, that's why I chose to ask here first. I think I should ask there again, too.

Comment: Dear confeng, StackOverFlow could be fastest Q/A site in web. In here, you can an answer in average 20-30 minute after the asking. Probably %70 is right. In Devexpress Support, they might be little slower than SO, but still they can feedback you an answer in same day. And they are really helpful people. And If you find the right answer, please share in here, maybe another people can get help with it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code central sample which you can also download and run locally:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E19.aspx

Btw, Soner points to some good info too.

Thanks.